# Can't parse Xml with Namespaces and in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-namespaces

I'm not able to parse an XML with namespaces:

Here's my XML:

```
<w:drawing>
    <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0">
    <wp:extent cx="2371148" cy="1999323"/>
    <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="0" b="0"/>
    <wp:docPr id="1" name="Image 1"/>
        <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
            <a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" noChangeAspect="1"/>
        </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
        <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
            <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                    <pic:nvPicPr>
                        <pic:cNvPr id="0" name="Image2.png"/>
                        <pic:cNvPicPr/>
                    </pic:nvPicPr>
                <pic:blipFill>
                    <a:blip r:embed="rId9">
                        <a:extLst>
                            <a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}">
                            <a14:useLocalDpi xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0"/>
                            </a:ext>
                            </a:extLst>
                    </a:blip>
                    <a:stretch>
                        <a:fillRect/>
                    </a:stretch>
                </pic:blipFill>
                    <pic:spPr>
                        <a:xfrm>
                            <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                            <a:ext cx="2371148" cy="1999323"/>
                        </a:xfrm>
                    <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                        <a:avLst/>
                    </a:prstGeom>
                    </pic:spPr>
                </pic:pic>
            </a:graphicData>
        </a:graphic>
    </wp:inline>
</w:drawing>
```

I would like to get the   tag, but This tag doesn't seem to be loaded in the xml.

I know the colons mean these are namespaces, that's why I tried to use getElementsByTagNameNS('*', 'blipFill'), but the result is only this xmlTag (not his children)

Here's a jsfiddle that shows that the  tag is empty

http://jsfiddle.net/TaGmk/1/

Comment: Remove `r:` in `<a:blip r:embed="rId9">`: http://jsfiddle.net/TaGmk/2/ But you'll also get a parse error node complaining `w:` prefix is not defined in your root element.

Comment: Yep, I have added the namespace definition at the beginning and it works now: `<?xml version="1.0" ?><w:document mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the correct namespace definition at the beginning of the document

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<w:document mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"   

xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main ...
```